# Translate excel inputs into json

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am trying to extract a json file with the following inputs in Excel.

[image]

To do that, I have a code as follows (in VBA):

```
Public Sub ExceltoJson()

Dim rng As Range, items As New Collection, myitem As New Dictionary, i As Integer, cell
Set rng = Range("A1:A3")
i = 0
For Each cell In rng
    Debug.Print (cell.Value)
    myitem("CurrentPromo") = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
    myitem("StartDateCP") = cell.Offset(2, 0).Value
    myitem("EndDateCP") = cell.Offset(3, 0).Value
    Set myitem = Nothing
    i = i + 1
    items.Add myitem
Next
'items.Add myitem
myfile = "C:\Users\gabriem\PycharmProjects\BigPromos" & "\json_vba.json"
Open myfile For Output As #1
Print #1, ConvertToJson(items, Whitespace:=2)
Close #1

End Sub
```

But, the result I get is:

```
[{"StartDateCP": "PastPromo","EndDateCP": "DPE16"},{"CurrentPromo":"PastPromo","StartDateCP": "DPE16"},{}]
```

This is not what I am looking for. I need each label together with its unique value.

Can anyone guide me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is iterate over the headers and add the next row's value into a dictionary to generate the JSON string.

It looks like you are using the VBA-JSON project, but if you aren't the solution below requires this project to function, so make sure add this to your project. You can get a copy of the project [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON). Additionally, you must add a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` for this to work.

Assuming you have headers in `A1:C1` and data in `A2:C2` in `Sheet1` the below should work. The headers are the **Keys** and the next row is the **Value**.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub createJSON()
    Dim ws      As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rng     As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C1")
    Dim cll     As Range
    Dim dict    As Dictionary: Set dict = New Dictionary
    Dim JSON    As String

    'Add the items to a dictionary
    For Each cll In rng
        If Not dict.exists(cll.Value) Then dict.Add cll.Value, cll.Offset(1, 0).Value
    Next

    JSON = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(dict, Whitespace:=2)
    Debug.Print JSON
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Ryan. The code works perfeclty. Just one thing to clarify: I do not know why the fourth column gets registered as this: {
  "CurrentPromo": "DPE17",
  "StartDateCP": "2017-09-28T05:00:00.000Z",
  "EndDateCP": "2017-10-18T05:00:00.000Z",
  "": "PastPromo",
  "PastPromo": "DPE16",
  "StartDatePP": "2016-09-28T05:00:00.000Z",
  "EndDatePP": "2016-10-18T05:00:00.000Z",
}. It is duplicated. Do you know why?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. There were only 3 columns in the example I posted. Maybe this is a new question?